# post values to external page explicitly PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I want to post values to a page through a hyperlink in another page. Is it possible to do that?

Let's say I have a page results.php which has the starting line,

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['posted_value']))
{
echo "expected value"; 
// do something with the data
}
else
{
echo "no the value expected";
}
```

If from another page say `link.php` I place a hyperlink like this:

`<a href="results.php?posted_value=1">` , will this be accepetd by the results page?

If instead if I replace the above starting line with

`if(isset($_REQUEST['posted_value']))`, will this work?

I believe the above `hyperlink` evaluates to GET, but since the only visibility difference between GET and POST that is `you can see parameters in the address bar with GET`

But, is there any other way to place a hyperlink which can post values to a page? or can we use jquery in the place of hyperlink to `POST` the values?

Can anyone please suggest me something on this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a POST request using a hyperlink. This will always issue a GET request. You need to use javascript to do that. With jQuery is very easy using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Sample code:

html:

```
<a id="MyLink" href="#">Link</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $("MyLink").click(function () {
      $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
    });
});
```

Of course you can do everything in html code, but it isn't recommended:

```
<a href='#' onclick='$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )'>Link</a>
```

Comment: not sure how to output a hyperlink with jquery to POST values

Comment: is there any real difference if I place this `.click` javascript code in the `head` region or in the `body`?

Comment: It is better to put it in the head section. In this case I don't think it will make a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the query string (and consequently `$_GET`) whether the request type is GET or POST. POST passes additional parameters to the script's standard input which are parsed to generate `$_POST` and `$_FILES`. Clicking a hyperlink generates a GET request unless you override it using JavaScript by simulating submission of a POST form.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct. Hyperlinks cannot POST to a PHP script, only pass parameters as GET. You can use the `$.ajax` method in jQuery as kgiannakakis suggested, which will POST to a PHP script, but then you would only change parts of a page and not the entire page.

Another solution is to use a form and button - you can style it as link if you like.

```
<style>
.formlink {
    display: inline;
}
.formlink input.submit {
    display: inline;
    background: transparent none;
    border: 0;
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<form class="formlink" method="post" action="script.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_value" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post 1" class="submit" />
</form>
```